# Error: No emulator images (avds) found. in ionic 2

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I'm trying to run ionic emulate android, but it showing error

```
Error: No emulator images (avds) found.
1. Download desired System Image by running: "C:\Users\-------\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\tools\android.bat" sdk
2. Create an AVD by running: "C:\Users\---------\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\tools\android.bat" avd
HINT: For a faster emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the HAXM device driver
```

i'm tried to open AVD manager but no use

```
C:\Users\---------\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\tools>android avd
```

[image: AVD Manager]

[image: AVD create]

[image: Android sdk manager]

Can anyone help me to resolve these issue
Thanks in advance

Comment: So what parts of the Android SDK have you downloaded - item 1 (android.bat) in your error message.

Comment: have you downloaded any  emulators ??

Comment: @rishit_s i have downloaded andrios studio thats it. and i'm updating my question by adding andriod sdk manager

Comment: @NunnaS you need to download api's aswell i would suggest android 6.0

Comment: Thanks i'm new to these topic. can u please help me, how to get that by providing any url link. @rishit_s

Comment: using avd manager...

Comment: check out this link https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html

Comment: Thanks For help after install that i will let u know @rishit_s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your command prompt run `android avd`

Create your emulator and try ionic emulate android again

Answer (score 2):

In more recent versions, `android avd` has been replaced by:

`avdmanager`

(You can find it in your *.../android/sdk/tools/bin* folder)